# Turn off notifications for Meteor collections

Tags: meteor

How do I tell Meteor to stop publishing changes on a collection (for a moment)? 
Also how to tell it to resume and that the collection changed?

Basically (on the server):

```
People = new Meteor.Collection("people")
insertPeople = ->
  // Don't notify clients of the following changes
  // Insert a bunch of people into the People collection
  // Resume notifications
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a flag in each document, 'updating'.
Add the new ones with this set to true; render their template with a css class that hides them based on this field.
When ready, update the collection to updating: false.  They will be visible pretty quickly.

This being said, there are events you can plug into to make transitions more pleasant/animated.  Didn't think you were asking that, but it may be a better answer.

To the comment:
Inserting a template for an additional document triggers DOM changes, which are fairly expensive, and then the device has to figure out how to display.  Updating a property requires just the second part, that the device has to figure out how to display.

Comment: What is the difference between inserting a document and have it displayed on the page, and updating a property and have it displayed on the page?

Comment: DOM changes are fairly expensive, compared to class changes over visibility.If the updating software is smart enough, which I think Meteor is, changing a class on a div won't cause any DOM manipulations.

Comment: I'm confused. I agree that once the element is in the DOM then updating the property is less expensive, but we still have to get the element in the DOM in the first place (with or without the updating property). What I have is 'insert into DOM and render' one by one. What you seem to propose is 'insert into DOM' in bulk then 'render' in bulk.

Comment: I get your abstract point.  I read your question to be concerned with the user experience, not for each cycle in one of the cores of a modern pentium or smartphone chip...  If your app is bombarded with so much data that the difference between bulk inserting x records into the dom vs inserting them individually is a concern, you probably have a different problem than the one we started with above.  You may be questioning server vs client rendered html

Comment: I may be asking the wrong question then. My query only retrieves the top 10 items sorted by a field. When there are a lot of inserts and updates to the collection the page freezes. I assumed that the client is being notified of all these updates and that's why it's freezing. That's why I asked for a way to turn off the notifications. What do you think?

Comment: That should be a new question.  Something is wrong.  You could try using a mongo db that's not part of your project, like a free one, to see if your machine is overburdened.

Meteor is a strong product, and got substantial financing.  Copy a subset into github so someone could clone and see.  Or, start over, implement just this part again, see where it gets unreasonable.

Make copies then Upgrade everything.